# How to set a debugger flag on C build?

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, shell, command-line

I'am following a tutorial on making a game in C/C++. The building part takes place with just a .bat file. I'll show it.

```
@echo off
mkdir ..\build
pushd ..\build
cl -zi s:\games\game1\code\win32_game1.cpp user32.lib
popd
```

The flag -zi is used for getting the debugger output/information. The only problem is that when I run this script in the command line I get the following error:

```
Ignoring unknown option "-zi"
```

Can somebody tells me why -zi isn't working or what I can use instead? I'm using Visual Studio 2017.

Comment: Have a read of and remember switches are case-sensitive: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fwkeyyhe.aspx

Comment: `/zi` != `/Zi` != `/ZI`.

Comment: Voting to close as a simple typo. VS compiler switches are *case sensitive*.

Comment: Thanks! @JesperJuhl I got it. Case-sensitive indeed Richard.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Just curious. Why is -zi working with my instructor?

Comment: @Thijs Moens - No idea. I guess it *doesn't* and whomever wrote that just made a typo when putting the instructions online.